# How do I refer to enclosing "this" in a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

The following macro, extracted from a larger example, is supposed to create a tree with nothing but a reference to `this`:

```
def echoThisImpl(c:Context): c.Expr[Any] = {
  import c.universe._

  val selfTree = This(c.enclosingClass.symbol)
  c.Expr[AnyRef](selfTree)
}

def echoThis: Any = macro CallMacro.echoThisImpl
```

But a call to `echoThis` such as

```
object Testing extends App {
  val thisValue = CallMacro.echoThis
  println(thisValue)
}
```

fails to compile, with the message

```
[error] /home/rafael/dev/scala/goose/goose-macros/src/test/scala/Testing.scala:8: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : <noprefix>
[error]  required: Any
[error]   val thisValue = CallMacro.echoThis
```

If I set the *-Ymacro-debug-lite* flag the generated tree is `This(newTermName("<local Testing>"))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two options of achieving what you want:

1) Use `This(tpnme.EMPTY)`. Currently this doesn't compile, so you'll have to use `This(newTypeName(""))` instead, but in RC1 this will be fixed.

2) Use `This(c.enclosingClass.symbol.asModule.moduleClass)`. Currently this doesn't work, because of https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6394, but in RC1 this will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for responding Eugene. It wasn't quite enough to get me through. IIUC `c.prefix` is an expression for the tree that refers to the `object` where the macro is defined.

Comment: (continuing) 
`This()` takes a symbol, and I believe I'm looking for the symbol referring to the enclosing class of the macro call. 

I want the call

`    def echoThis: Any = macro MacroImpl.echoThis`

to be the same as

`    def echoThis: Any = this`